# storing array in a sql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I started getting into arrays and don't quite get it to work well. I'm used to work with explode/implode functions but I though arrays would make my life easier in this part of the code. Here is the function called:

```
function save_event($event_items = NULL) {
include 'connect.php';

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sqla = "
INSERT INTO `event`(`event_items`, `event_entered`)
    VALUES ('$event_items','$now')";

    $resulta = mysqli_query($link, $sqla);
    if(!$resulta)
        {
        echo '<br/>An error occurred while inserting your data. Please try again later.<br/>';
        }
    else
        { echo 'this is the variable to be stored:<br/>';
          print_r($event_items);

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE event_entered = '".$now."'";
          $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

          if($result)
            { while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                  { echo '<br/></br>This is the value of the database:<br/>';
                    print_r ($row['event_items']);
                  }
            }
          }
}
```

This function prints:

```
this is the variable to be stored:
Array( [0] => Array ( [item] => Powered Speaker [note] => [quantity] => 2 [price] => 200.00 [category] => Audio ) [1] => Array ( [item] => Wireless Microphone [note] => Lavalier [quantity] => 3 [price] => 175.00 [category] => Audio ))

This is the value of the database:
Array
```

In phpMyAdmin, all I see in the column `event_items` is the word `Array`.

Additional info:
I have a table called Groups, each group will have one or multiple orders (another table called Order) and each order will have also one or multiple events (another table). Lastly, each event will have one or multiple items (each item with its corresponding price, quantity, note and category), which are stored in one (or many) columns in the Event table.

Comment: You can't just insert an array and expect it to be stored the way you do here. You can go back to using explode and implode or normalize the schema and store one value per row.

Comment: `array` means that the variable to be stored was array not a string, as it should be. So the problem is in your `INSERT` query. Consider using `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize your array with the serialize() function.

Example:

```
serialize($event_items);
```

> Generates a storable representation of a value.
>
> This is useful for storing or passing PHP values around without losing
>   their type and structure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 9):

Don't try to store an array in one field. You should store each item in the array as it's own row in a related table.

Comment: Before trying to make arrays, I was using implode/explode and have columns named item, note, price, etc. Is that the way to go?

Comment: You should have one table that holds the parent item. (An order?) And a table that holds each product (columns would be item, note, price, etc). It should also have the order_id. Google "data normalization" if you need more.

Comment: Wow, I think there are things that I though were not worth to tell but I see the need to now: I have a table called Groups, each group will have one or multiple orders (another table called Order) and each order will have also one or multiple events (another table). Lastly, each event will have one or multiple items (each item with its corresponding price, quantity, note and category), which are stored in one (or many) columns in the Event table.

Comment: Sounds good. Categories should be it's own table, and you store categoryId.

Comment: Now, let me bother you a little bit more: the way AI had it before was something like imploding the variables 'item', 'quantity', etc and storing them that way. Should I use that approach or I would be better off using arrays (Or I should NEVER store arrays).

Comment: Never store arrays. Or the result of imploding them, serializing them, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert multiple values in a single database record, this is not impossible but it's also not recommended in general.

The main reason someone would do this would be for optimization, which is not at all something you should worry about for now.

What you really want to do is review your database schema, if you wish to store an array of value, you need to create a new row (record) for each of those. This might necessitate the creation of another table, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I'm actually coming from that approach! I just thought an array would be easier to work with. Now, serialize/unserialize are looking pretty good to learn :-)

Comment: Serializing is certainly a possible approach that will work, but it's better practice to create a new table for the records. Even while working on sites with over 500000 unique visitors a month, we very rarely need to do something like that for optimization.

Comment: serialize is for using an array - not the right way to go here.